# Is Exterminatus ever used offensively?

Tags: warhammer-40k

It seems to me that it would be useful to send raiding parties deep into enemy territory, equipped with Exterminatus weaponry.  Instead of just using Exterminatus as a kind of scorched earth tactic when they are about to lose a world, why does the Imperium not use it on enemy worlds?

Or is this actually done and I just don't know about it?

Answer (score 4):

The Imperium does not like to waste planets that it could recover someday. A planet seized by secessionist humans, eldar, orks, tau, etc. can be recaptured and returned to Imperial service. These planets represent a resource far more valuable than the Guard and Space Marine forces used to assault them. Even planets that have fallen to Chaos may in theory be redeemed, though not one that has been corrupted into a Daemon World.

For instance, many of the planets of the Sabbat Worlds, as detailed in the Gaunt's Ghosts novels and supplementary works, are former Chaos-held planets that were reclaimed by the Imperial crusade and resettled. Some, like the forge world Urdesh, have changed hands numerous times because of their strategic value.

Performing Exterminatus is a last resort for when a planet has *no* chance of being reclaimed in the foreseeable future, often because there will be nothing left *to* reclaim. The main threats that fall into this scope are tyranids, necrons, and the imminent creation of Daemon Worlds. (The last one is especially common because it can be suspected of otherwise ordinary planets. In contrast, an active necron presence or tyranid fleet is generally pretty obvious.)

So why are these worlds only subjected to Exterminatus as they're falling from Imperial rule, and not after? It depends on the threat.

Daemon Worlds don't really exist in real space any more. Caught partially inside the Warp, they may be subject to bizarre physical laws that bear little or no relation to what we'd expect. The upshot is that it can be difficult or impossible to actually perform Exterminatus on them, or even predict what the effects of trying will be.

Planets conquered by the tyranids offer little to either side. When the tyranids finish digesting biomass from the planet, they will return to their fleets, leaving only a small infiltration force behind, if that. The stay-behind forces tend to be dug in deeply and are known to survive orbital bombardment or even Exterminatus. In general, hunting down the hive fleets themselves is considered a better use of the Navy's time and munitions.

Finally, the necrons do use their tomb worlds, and the Imperium would probably love to blow them up, but the fact of the matter is that the necrons have their own fleets and the Navy doesn't relish engaging them. A "raiding party" with the sort of firepower necessary to cleanse a necron planet would be obliterated before it got close.

Comment: There can also be cases where the inquisition decides Exterminatus is better then letting certain secrets about a planet get out, or where a planet is to far out of the way to warrant a full scale assault and drawn out war.

Answer (score 3):

The Imperial Fists used their mobile fortress-monastery to perform Exterminatus on the Iron Warriors' fortress world of [Malodrax](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Malodrax).

> Malodrax is a Fortress World belonging to the Iron Warriors Chaos Space Marines under Warsmith Shon'tu, notable for being the location of Imperial Fist Captain Darnath Lysander's imprisonment and torture. When Lysander escaped the planet he returned with reinforcements, ravaging the planet in an act of vengeance.[2] Later with the help of Ork allies, Shon'tu built a new powerbase upon the planet. However, the planet was completely destroyed by the Phalanx in the Fall of Malodrax.[1]
>
> 1: Codex: Space Marines (5th Edition), pg. 91
>
> 2: Sentinels of Terra — The Fall of Malodrax

The end of the battle [is descibed](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Fall_of_Malodrax):

> the Phalanx moved into position aboard(sic) Malodrax and enacted Exterminatus, winning the day.

See also: wh40k.lexicanum.com has [a list of worlds](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Exterminatus) destroyed by exterminatus.

Scanning that list, it does seem like most victims are Imperial worlds.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any situation where an Exterminatus has ever been used offensively and there is reason to think it wouldn't.

1. An Exterminatus is not something that can be done in a fly-by. Take the description of the Exterminatus on Isstvan III in *Galaxy in Flames* by Ben Counter:

> a rampant organism that destroyed life in all its forms and wiped out every shred of organic matter on the surface of a planet within hours. The magnitude of this new knowledge, and its implications, staggered Tarvitz and he felt his breath coming in short, painful gasps as he attempted to reconcile what he knew with what he had just learned.
>
> His Legion was preparing to kill the planet below and he knew with sudden clarity that it could not be alone in this. To saturate a planet with enough virus warheads to destroy all life would take many ships and with a sick jolt of horror, he knew that such an order could only have come from the Warmaster.

1. The entire fleet of the Death Guard was in system and Tarvitz believed this fleet was not enough for Exterminatus by virus bombs (Life Eater Virus).
2. The coordination needed to synchronize this is immense.
3. Ships need to be in low orbit in order to bombard a planet. This opens them up for attack by a planetary battery. (quote again from *Galaxy in Flames*).

> The only reason to move a vessel after a launch was to move into low orbit in preparation for a bombardment.

2. Exterminatus is not the weapon of choice by the Imperium:

> Exterminatus is typically only used as a last resort, when the price of holding or retaking the world for the Emperor is deemed too high, or the threat of mutation, disease or Chaos heresy spreading to the rest of the Imperium is too great to contain by conventional means.
>
> From the [Fandom Article on Exterminatus](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Exterminatus)

3. Only a selected few can order an Exterminatus.

> Thus Exterminatus has very rarely been used on vital or strategically valuable planets to the Imperium. Typically, the order may only be given by a high-ranking Imperial commander in the Astra Militarum, Imperial Navy or the Adeptus Astartes, or by a full member of the Imperial Inquisition.
>
> Again from the Fandom Article on Exterminatus.

In an offensive action, an enemy worth of an Exterminatus (it's useless to use Exterminatus on a medival society, Imperial Guard is sufficient for that scenario) has planetary defense that would probably shred the required ships into pieces while they try to execute the Exterminatus. Furthermore, you can't use the planet anymore as it's a barren piece of rock floating around. Also, it first needs the attention of somebody high enough in the hierarchy to order to exterminate this planet (and probably also nobody on the same or higher level to veto the Exterminatus). You therefore pay a high price in ships and do gain nothing, the commander exposes himself to political threat. I doubt any high-ranking commander would approve this.